# I want to make my own c# debugger - how would one do that? What tools should I be using?

Tags: c#, architecture

I'm interested in making a program that will take c# code and allow me to step through the execution of that code line by line - a debugger.

How would I go about this project without having to write a whole c# compiler? I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio, but I want my software to be as independent of their debugger implementation as possible.

Comment: Writing a visual studio alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [ICorDebug](https://web.archive.org/web/20150918000511/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2004/10/05/237954.aspx), the managed debugging API.
You can use  `csc.exe` to compile the code (this is included in a standard .Net Framework installation and wrapped by the [CSharpCodeProvider class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)), then execute the assembly, attach the debugger, and step through the code.

Note that you would probably still need a C# *parser* to figure out where you are in the source.
The PDB file will contain some of this information; I'm not sure how much.

Note that most of the features in VS's debugger which we take for granted (especially the Watch window and variable tooltips) will require painful re-implementation.  ([Func-eval](https://web.archive.org/web/20140505034233/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/03/05/writing-funceval-in-a-debugger.aspx)s)

Comment: You don't need a parser just for stepping around. The PDB file contains all the information about what text span corresponds to what "sequence point". (Which is different from the C definition of "sequence point", hence the quotation marks.)  You do need a parser if you want a watch window, expression evaluator, and so on, but of course you only need to parse expressions. If you decide to not allow lambdas then that is a pretty small subset to parse.

Comment: @Eric: Thanks; I've been wondering about that.  Does VS really not use a parser to display breakpoints?

Comment: Obviously, you will need a parser for datatips.

Comment: The debugger does not need to parse the code to do breakpoints. Breakpoints work solely off of knowing what span of text corresponds to what span of IL instructions.